# Saving website content as HTML for Offline use with link working

Tags: web, save, offline, offline-browsing

I'm having a site done in wordpress with some 10 pages. I'll need to save it, the whole site with the links working for offline use every time i update the content. Now what am doing is save each page then link everything etc.. but i want to do this programing.. so i dont have to do manually or are there any tools or class already?

UPDATE:
I'm downloading for creating a offline documentation kind of stuff, which will be distributed on CD's so links should be relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **wget**, check the -k option

```
  -k,  --convert-links      make links in downloaded HTML point to local files.
```

Reference: http://www.linuxask.com/questions/mirror-a-web-site-using-wget

Answer (score 0):

If you set the links to a relative path (eg `href="/foo/bar.html"`), this can be accomplished.

Otherwise, I suggest setting up Apache or IIS on your local machine to be your test environment, and upload it to the web server when your code is ready for production.